# Android: Retrieving string from php page using split from the * character

Tags: android, parsing, split

Can someone please tell my why this causes my application to crash? This same code works on my other application that's why I'm so confused.

What I am trying to do is tell my application to go to http://omarcomputerservices.com/cartoons/cartoons.php?getCartoon&ID=1 and then split the parsed string from the '*' character. Then add it to the array.

I have added the internet permission.

```
package com.omarreyes.youtubechannels;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;


public class StartingPoint extends Activity 
{


    ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);




        Button get = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        get.setOnClickListener(listener);  
    }

    private OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {


            getImages();



        }
    };

    private void getImages()
    {
        try 
        {
            // Create a URL object
            URL url = new URL("http://omarcomputerservices.com/cartoons/cartoons.php?getCartoon&ID=1");

            // Read all of the text returned by the HTTP server
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            String htmlText;

            while ((htmlText = in.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                // Keep in mind that readLine() strips the newline characters
                String[] data = htmlText.split("\\*");



                images.add(data[0].toString());


            }
            in.close();
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Post your complete logcat please!

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance I see at least one reason why your app crashes - the `getImages()` method tries to perform a network operation on the main (UI) thread.

Since network operations are time consuming, they must run in their own thread. To enforce this rule, starting with Android API Level 11, if you attempt to perform a network operation on UI thread, a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown.

To solve this issue you should put the code that accesses the network into a separate thread, for example into an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: I am going to try this out real quick

Comment: try to run on lower versions, if it does work well then I guess it's the problem with Network operation.